# How to mock local variable obtained from another method of tested class?

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

I have following class

```
class MyClass{
   public void m(InputStream is){
       ...
       Parser eParser = getExcelFileParser();
       eParser.parse(is);
       ...
       eParser.foo();
       eParser.bar();

   }
   public ExcelFileParser getExcelFileParser(){
       ...
   } 
}
```

How to write unit test for method `m` at this situation? I want to mock  `eParser` object only.

Is it possible?

I use Mockito and PowerMockito

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what you want in Mockito (no PowerMock needed) using a `spy` without changing your code at all.

In your unit test you need to do something like the following:

```
ExcelFileParser parser = mock(ExcelFileParser.class);
MyClass myClass = spy(new MyClass());
doReturn(parser).when(myClass).getExcelFileParser();
```

Comment: Yes! The spy only replaces the methods you tell.it to

Answer (score 0):

Can you pass AnotherObject as a parameter into the method m rather than calling getAnotherObject() in the method itself?

Comment: Then use Mockito to mock the getAnotherObject, eg when(myClass.getAnotherObject()).thenReturn(myNewMockObject)

Answer (score 0):

Preface:  I use EasyMock not Mockito so this may be a bit off.

Can't you create an inner subclass of MyClass in your test that overrides getExcelFileParser and has it return a mock?  Like this:

```
public class MyClassMock extends MyClass {

     ExcelFileParser _mock;

     public MyClassMock(ExcelFileParser mock) {
          _mock = mock;
     }

     @Override
     public ExcelFileParser getExcelFileParser() {
         return _mock;
     }
}
```

I haven't tested this so there could be issues with this, but the basic idea should be right.